# How to assign a label to a random number (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift

I have 49 labels (from a1 to g7) and I want to randomly choose one of them.        I set an array

```
let array = [a1, a2, ...., g6, g7]
```

And then the function to select the Random Label

```
let RandomGen = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
```

Once I chose the random label, how can I operate with it?
I want to change its background color, but if I write

```
RandomGen.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
```

it shows this compile error Value of type 'String' has no member 'backgroundColor', because of course RandomGen is a variable, not a label.
How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`RandomGen` is a number between `0` and `array.count` *(from `0` to `array.count - 1`)*. You need to use that to get the label from the `array` and then change its background color:

```
array[RandomGen].backgroundColor = .green
```

Comment: It's a good note for me that you could `.green` without `UIColor` before it, I though it is illegal since `UIColor` is a class but not an enum, any idea? :)

Comment: @AhmadF It is not a rule for only enums but all variables whose type can be inferred. In this case, class name is inferred because compiler already  knows that `.backgroundColor` accepts a value of type `UIColor` so it can totally be omitted.

Comment: Type of the `array` is also inferred so you don't have to write `let array: [UILabel]` or do a typcasting like `(array[RandomGen] as! UILabel).backgroundColor = ...` as well.

Comment: That's right, you would need to do such a thing if the array contains other types of *UIView*, such as a UIButton for example; It would be `[UIView]`...

Answer (score 0):

After generating (declaring) a random index for getting a label:

```
let randomElementIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
```

you could use it as follows:

```
let myRandomLabel = array[randomElementIndex]
```

assuming that `myRandomLabel` is a UILabel (since `array` is an array of UILabels), you could assign the desired background color for it:

```
// for instance:
myRandomLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
```

Note that implementing:

```
RandomGen.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
```

is quite *wrong*, `RandomGen` is an *Int* which should be represents the random index, but not the label itself.